# Writing Custom CIFilter in iOS 11, Metal Linker

Tags: ios, xcode, metal, ciimage, cikernel

I'm trying to compile custom filters using MSL as discussed in [this 2017 WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/510/) and in [this part of the CIFilter Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreimage/cikernel/2880194-init). Without the MTLLINKER_FLAGS my program runs smoothly, but with the flags turned on (value set to -cifilter), my program's metal device.defaultLibrary fails to return vertex and fragment funcations. In fact, when I print out the library's function names they are all empty.

```
guard let library = device.newDefaultLibrary() else { return }
let pipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
pipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = 1
pipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = .bgra8Unorm
pipelineDescriptor.depthAttachmentPixelFormat = .invalid

NSLog("%@", library.functionNames)
pipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "mapTexture")
pipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library.makeFunction(name: "displayTexture")

do {
    try renderPipelineState = device.makeRenderPipelineState(descriptor: pipelineDescriptor)
}
catch {
    NSLog("%@", error.localizedDescription)
    assertionFailure("Failed creating a render state pipeline. Can't render the texture without one.")
    return
}
```

Metal Code:

```
    #include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

typedef struct {
    float4 renderedCoordinate [[position]];
    float2 textureCoordinate;
} TextureMappingVertex;

vertex TextureMappingVertex mapTexture(unsigned int vertex_id [[ vertex_id ]]) {
    float4x4 renderedCoordinates = float4x4(float4(-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                                            float4( 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                                            float4(-1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0),
                                            float4( 1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0));
    float4x2 textureCoordinates = float4x2(float2( 0.0, 1.0),
                                           float2( 1.0, 1.0),
                                           float2( 0.0, 0.0),
                                           float2( 1.0, 0.0));
    TextureMappingVertex outVertex;
    outVertex.renderedCoordinate = renderedCoordinates[vertex_id];
    outVertex.textureCoordinate = textureCoordinates[vertex_id];

    return outVertex;
}

fragment half4 displayTexture(TextureMappingVertex mappingVertex [[ stage_in ]],
                              texture2d<float, access::sample> texture [[ texture(0) ]]) {
    constexpr sampler s(address::clamp_to_edge, filter::linear);

    return half4(texture.sample(s, mappingVertex.textureCoordinate));
}
```

Comment: I'm no Metal aficionado, but it rather looks like you're trying to extract your custom functions from the default system library, not your own metal file.

Comment: Oh, looking back now it does look like my library init is wrong. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem! Does it work now?

Comment: Since you are writing a custom filter I guess you already have found sucess with what I am stuck at. I am trying to apply a simple vignette filter to a live camera feed using metal. The results are pretty slow and laggy, please check this if you can tell me what is missing:https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898780/1364053

Comment: also the value to set is not -cifilter but -cikernel